# Selenium testing : How to bypass okta in selenium

Tags: spring, selenium, spring-security, okta, okta-api

We have recently implemented okta into our application.

Whenever the user wants to login it will ask for an okta code which will keep on changing every 30 seconds, but while running selenium how should I enter the okta code?

Can I bypass okta for selenium Automation? Or what should I do ?

Ideas and solutions are appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

- Direct by pass is not supported by selenium right now.
- One solution for this scenarios is to create a dedicated test credential and bypass MFA for this credential in Okta configuration.

You can whitelist the test account to not be prompted for MFA under -
`Admin >> Security >> Authentication >> Sign On`

Reference - https://devforum.okta.com/t/method-to-bypass-multi-factor-athuntication/4669